# Wrap with multiple XML tags without create diferent classes C#

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core, xmlserializer

I have the class

```
    public class TestModel
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

which is converted with the following xml

```
<TestModel>
  <Number>2</Number>
  <Text>text</Text>
</TestModel>
```

But i need to wrap this with multiples xml tags

```
<Wrapper1>
   <Wrapper2>
      <TestModel>
         <Number>2</Number>
         <Text>text</Text>
      </TestModel>
   </Wrapper2>
</Wrapper1>
```

Is there any attribute to be able to put this type of wrappers? Like

```
[XElementWrapper("Wrapper1", "Wrapper2")]
public class TestModel
{
..
}
```

I dont want to create dummy classes only to contains the wrappers or create the xml element by code

Comment: You can easily wrap your serialized result into root nodes with the help of all other Xml tools available in .NET like: XmlWriter or even by transforming your Xml with Xslt's...

Comment: No. You can't create an additional tags using attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make it by implementing [IXmlSerializable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable?view=netcore-3.1)